# Django Rest Framework filtering calculated model property

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, django-filters

Sorry for a newbie question. I have a following model:

```
class WeightSlip(models.Model):

    grossdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    grossweight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    taredate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    tareweight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    vehicle = models.CharField(max_length=12)

    @property
    def netweight(self):
        return self.grossweight - self.tareweight

    @property
    def slipdate(self):
        if self.grossdate > self.taredate:
           return grossdate.date()
        else:
           return taredate.date()
```

Serializer:

```
class WeightSlipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   class Meta:
      model = models.WeightSlip
      fields = ('grossdate', 'grossweight', 'taredate', 'tareweight', 'slipdate', 'netweight', 'vehicle')
      read_only_fields = ('slipdate', 'netweight')
```

I am trying to use the [django-rest-framework-filters](https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters) to filter on the calculated 'netweight' and 'slipdate' properties:

```
class WeightSlipFilter(FilterSet):

   class Meta:
       model = WeightSlip
       fields = ('slipdate', 'netweight', 'vehicle')
```

This gives me an error:

```
TypeError: 'Meta.fields' contains fields that are not defined on this FilterSet: slipdate, netweight
```

Is there a workaround to this problem other than adding the calculated fields to the database ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can create custom filter for `slipdate, netweight` that will evaluate and filter this fields in db. For this you can use [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) and [F expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/)

```
from django.db.models import F, Case, When

class WeightSlipFilter(FilterSet):
    slipdate = DateTimeFilter(method='filter_slipdate')
    netweight = NumberFilter(method='filter_netweight')

    class Meta:
        model = WeightSlip
        fields = ('slipdate', 'netweight', 'vehicle')

    def filter_netweight(self, queryset, value):
        if value:
            queryset = queryset.annotate(netweight=F('grossweight') - F('tareweight')).filter(netweight=value)
        return queryset

    def filter_slipdate(self, queryset, value):
        if value:
            queryset = queryset.annotate(slipdate=Case(When(grossdate__gt=F('taredate'), then=F('grossdate')), default=F('taredate')).filter(slipdate=value)
        return queryset
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, great help since most of my project contains filtering on calculated fields.

Comment: from django_filters.rest_framework import (
    NumberFilter,
    DateTimeFilter,
)

Answer (score 4):

Note that if you're using the latest version of django-filter, `Filter.method` takes 4 arguments, like so:

```
def filter_slipdate(self, queryset, name, value):
    if value:
        queryset = queryset.annotate(slipdate=Case(When(grossdate__gt=F('taredate'), then=F('grossdate')), default=F('taredate')).filter(slipdate=value)
    return queryset
```

```

Answer (score 0):

Extending the answer further. With the latest django and drf version one might experience an exception like this.

**Exception**

> > File "/home/USER/.env/drf3/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 76, in **iter**
> > setattr(obj, attr_name, row[col_pos])
> > AttributeError: can't set attribute

**Versions Used:** `Django==3.1` `djangorestframework==3.11.1` `django-filter==2.3.0`

The **solution** that worked for me is this where slipdate and netweight requires model name to be used in the queryset...

```
def filter_slipdate(self, queryset, name, value):
    if value:
       queryset = queryset.annotate(WeightSlip__slipdate=Case(When(grossdate__gt=F('taredate'), then=F('grossdate')), default=F('taredate'))).filter(WeightSlip__slipdate=value)
    return queryset

def filter_netweight(self, queryset, name, value):
    if value:
        queryset = queryset.annotate(WeightSlip__netweight=F('grossweight') - F('tareweight')).filter(WeightSlip__netweight=value)
    return queryset
    return queryset
```